# Scala best practice on using self in method

Tags: scala

HI I have a case when calling a method to use self. Now not sure the best practice to do this in Scala.  I have created a example of how I'm doing it just wanted to ask is this the best way of doing so.

```
sealed trait Animal {
  // match on self
  final def speak(): Unit = {
    this match {
      case Cat(name) => println("spoken like a Cat named: " + name)
      case Dog(name) => println("spoken like a Dog named: " + name)
      case Pig(name) => println("spoken like a Pig named: " + name)
    }
  }
  final def whoAmI(): Unit = {
    this match {
      case Cat(_) => println("I am a Cat")
      case Dog(_) => println("I am a Dog")
      case Pig(_) => println("Could be a Pig")
    }
  }
}
final case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal
final case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal
final case class Pig(name: String) extends Animal
```

Comment: As you can see form sample I want to match on type when calling method. I've had to use this sample as I cannot show our production code, But its the same things I have a method this needs to know what sub type called the method.

Answer (score 4):

If your requirement is *only* to know which sub-type is used, it can be accessed in a more straightforward manner with just `this.getClass()`:

```
sealed trait Animal {

  val name: String

  final def speak(): Unit =
    println(s"spoken like a ${this.getClass.getSimpleName} named: ${name}")

  final def whoAmI(): Unit =
    println(s"I am a ${this.getClass.getSimpleName}")

}
```

If all the implementing sub-types are characterized by a `name`, that would be convenient to declare an abstract `val name: String`, which will allow to access the field in `speak()`.

For a use case like this the matchers are not the best option: for each implementing sub-type you have to add an entry in the matchers (may become difficult to maintain). I'd suggest using inheritance: if you have a behavior differentiated among the sub-types, declare an abstract method in the trait, call it from it, but its implementations should remain at sub-types level.

Comment: Thanks, The classes are not like above or contain a pram called "name", I was just using as example of what i have. My real code has a few prams for each case class. I just wanted to known if that is the right way to switch on self from a ADT by adding a static method to the sealed trait and then from within the method body switch on self.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your use of pattern matching on `this` is correct.
Since your hierarchy is sealed, you know, that there will not be any new types to account for - otherwise you should have the  `_ => ...` clause.

You can express your second case a bit simpler, since you dont care about the parameters, only about the type.

```
final def whoAmI(): Unit = {
this match {
  case _:Cat => println("I am a Cat")
  case _:Dog => println("I am a Dog")
  case _:Pig => println("Could be a Pig")
}
```

}

Finally, `this` always refers to the innermost type. In case of nested inner classes, you might want to use an alias, like `self`:

```
trait Tweeter {
   this: self =>  // reassign this into self, so it can be accessed from an inner class
```

Comment: I tried that but IntelliJ shows that as a error with Red under line so I had to use either Cat(_) or Cat(val)

Comment: Sorry, made a syntax typo earlier- fixed now. You have to use the `c:Cat`, or `_:Cat` construction - but still , no need to use the constructor arguments if you are only interested in the type.